# HTML thumbnail icon is broken for Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, thumbnails, thumbs.db

The problem is pretty straightforward. When I set an .html file to open with Chrome, the thumbnail icon is broken and doesn't show the Chrome logo.

I already tried deleting the IconCache.db file and then restarting my computer. Sadly, that didn't fix anything.

It works perfectly fine when I set the default program to IE or Firefox. Any idea on how to fix this issue?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this affect both Chrome 32-bit and Chrome 64-bit?  (If you haven't tried the other one, but you're using 64-bit Windows, then give it a shot.)  How about Chromium/Canary?  If you change icon sizes (small icons / large icons), does that have an impact?

Comment: @TOOGAM the same thing happens on 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: Interesting. The dragged shortcut that contains `html://...` is recognized by Windows as Chrome, but not the one that points to a local html file. Check the value of the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\http\UserChoice`, if `Progid` contains `ChromeHTML`.

Comment: @harrymc Progid contains `ChromeHTML` at that registry location.

Comment: I think that the problem is that the file is stored on the desktop itself. Try to put it in some folder, say`C:\Temp`, and to create a shortcut to it.

Comment: @harrymc the shortcut method also has a broken thumbnail. In fact, the thumbnail icon is broken all over the place :( It doesn't even show up right in Windows Explorer.

Comment: If you are on Windows 10, rebuilding the icon cache is described in [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/).

Comment: @harrymc I'm on Windows 7, but I tried that same method. The only difference was the file names. I'm about to say screw it :)

Comment: I sort of agree : The problem is trivial and more manipulation may cause more serious problems than the one you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File types and assocations are stored in the Registry, under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Interestingly, that branch isn't actually a hive of its own; it's put together on the fly by combining the `\SOFTWARE\Classes` data from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. HKCU takes precedence, but the `assoc` and `ftype` utilities look at HKLM.

The Chrome HTML file type is usually found at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML`. If yours is missing or doesn't specify an icon, save this as a `.reg` and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML]
@="Chrome HTML Document"
"AppUserModelId"="Chrome"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\Application]
"AppUserModelId"="Chrome"
"ApplicationIcon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe,0"
"ApplicationName"="Google Chrome"
"ApplicationDescription"="Access the Internet"
"ApplicationCompany"="Google Inc."

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\Shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\Shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" -- \"%1\""
```

(Remove the `(x86)` part if your Chrome installation is actually in the plain Program Files folder.)

Now we need to make sure the association between the file extension and file type is correct. Go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.html` and set the default value to `ChromeHTML`. That will change the value for your user account, but if you want to make sure it affects all users on the machine, update the version under HKLM as well. You will likely need to log off and back on to see the effect.

Comment: I ran through and did this, restarted my PC, but I still have the broken icon :\. One strange thing I have noticed is that I'm running Chrome 64-bit but the file locations are in Program Files (x86). I haven't understood why.

Comment: That's just the way it is also on my computer, but I don't have any problem with the desktop icon.

Comment: @DrZoo Hmm, interesting. What is the output of `assoc .html`? Also verify that the Chrome executable is exactly where my Registry fragment thinks it is. Does double-clicking the HTML file open it in Chrome? Do other users on the machine see the correct icon?

Comment: @BenN My `chrome.exe` is at C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application` like it is in your fragment. Double clicking the broken HTML thumbnail files does open them in Google Chrome too. In CMD the output of `assoc .html` is `.html=ChromeHTML`

Comment: @DrZoo Is the default value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.html` any different? Also, do `.htm` files have the right icon?

Comment: @BenN the HKCU .html and .htm are both ChromeHTML. `.htm` files also have the broken icon with Chrome.

Comment: @DrZoo Does anything change if you create a `DefaultIcon` subkey under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.html` and set its default value to the same thing as is under `ChromeHTML`? What if you use *Open with*, choose to always use the selected program, and select Chrome's executable manually? Also try creating another user on the machine and logging into it to see if the same problem occurs.

Comment: @BenN I tried creating the `DefaultIcon` and setting the default value to the same thing as ChromeHTML and it's still not working. I also tried manually going the the path of the `chrome.exe` with the open with property a while back. Doing so has the same result of a broken icon :\ I'll try to get someone else to log into an account later on today and see if they have the same issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56873/discussion-between-ben-n-and-drzoo).

Comment: I awareded you with the bounty reward. Although the problem didn't work in my situation, it seems like the most likely option to work for someone else who may experience the same issue.

Comment: This did not work for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue months ago. I solved by reinstalling the Chrome. It fixed for me.

Comment: I might try that again. I initially installed it with the offline installer, and then uninstalled and used the regular installer, but I had the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions offered in the other answers has worked,
and as the problem is not very critical, it is better to avoid solutions
that menace the stability of your computer.
I would suggest a workaround rather than a complete solution.

- Right-click the shortcut
- Choose **Properties**
- Click the **Change Icon ...** button
- Enter as the file name
  `C:\\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`
  and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Click **OK**.

This should change the icon to that of Chrome.
If this does not happen, then your Windows has a problem,
but I do not think that this problem merits any more radical solution.

Comment: I tried that too, but apparently you can only use the "Change Icon" option on the shortcut for the program. I tried this with multiple file extensions like `.html`, `.json`, `.js`, `.cpp`. None of them allowed me to change the icon image. I'm supposedly getting a new laptop in a few weeks so I'll just let it go and hope the same thing doesn't happen on the new one. Thanks for all of the suggestions!

Comment: Change Icon is not available for files that are *on* the desktop, and this will also happen on your new computer. You need to put instead the files in some other folder and use desktop shortcuts, rather than have them reside on the desktop. This is also better for backups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. open regedit from start Menu\ Run
2. go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
3. go to ChromeHTML
4. go to ShellEx
5. then rename IconHandler
6. log off or restart your PC.

Comment: Rename the value or change its value?   To what?

Comment: Just rename (  IconHandler ) sub key Simply with adding any thing, for example: to ( -IconHandler )

Comment: On Windows 10, I don't see ShellEx or IconHandler anywhere in `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML` or `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell`.